# How can I convert Entity to Object in java

Tags: java

I define a general List which can add any type elements, define as:`List<List<Object>> rows = new ArrayList<>()`; but when I get a list from my service layer, the compile process would throw a incompatible types exception, codes sample as below:

```
List<List<Object>> rows = new ArrayList<>();
List<ProductEntity> result = searchResponse.getProducts();
rows.add(result);
```

the exception is: `incompatible types: java.util.List<com.shopee.data.webapispec.brandseller.entity.product.ProductEntity> cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.lang.Object>` when I run the command "`mvn clean install`", anyone knows how to handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ProductEntity` is a sub class of `Object`. However `List<ProductEntity>` is not a subclass of `List<Object>`.

You need to have `List<List<? extends Object>> rows = new ArrayList<>();` to make this work.

See here for details on [Generics and Object Hierarchies](https://dzone.com/articles/how-do-generic-subtypes-work)